# How to modify unlink method in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

In odoo for each form view (like emplooyees) there is an "action" menu showing a "Delete" button. When the user click that button it deletes the record and shows the form view of the next record (employee) on the list. Is it possible to overrride de unlink method to redirect to the tree view of that entity once the record is deleted, instead of loading the next record?

Comment: That have to be done in the JavaScript Client of Odoo, because the business logic or ORM (in this case the unlink method) has nothing to do with this behavior.

Comment: thank you, coould you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: No i don't have an example.